# Array of class objects inside another class

Tags: php, class

I want to make var1 the array of instances of Class1. This array must be defined in Class2. How to do this correctly?

```
class Class1 {
  public $values = array();
}        

class Class2 {
    public $var1 = array();
    public $var1_ptr;
    public function setPtr(Class1 $var1) {
        $this->var1_ptr = $var1;
    }   
}

$cl2 = new Class2();
$cl2->sePtr($cl2->$var1[0]); // Here I want to access the first array's object of Class1.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You want to have an array of Class1 objects?

Comment: This seems like a combination of PHP and C++. What's with the _ptr?

Comment: @Rengers: Yes,exactly.I want it inside Class2 so that each object of Class2 would be linked to a different array of objects of Class1.

Comment: Your formatting makes no sense. First off, are you using Class2 to store references to the Class1 objects? Secondly, do you wish to be able to access each of these individually? Thirdly, will you be setting these objects externally? At the moment you're just trying to set an unused property as an unused array.

Comment: @Death: I want to be able to do something like this: $cl2->var1[$i]->values[$j] = 1; For this I need var1 be the array of CLass1 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store objects as array elements, and access them no differently as if they were their own variables. The same applies to storing them as a property of an object.

```
class Class1 {
    public $values = array();
}   

class Class2 {
    public $var1=array();
}

$cl2=new Class2();
$cl2->var1[]=new Class1; //Do this as many times as you want to store Class1 objects
```

To retrieve the $j-th value of the $i-th object stored in the array:

```
$retrieved_object=$cl2->var1[$i]->values[$j];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just populate the array with instances of Class1?

```
$var1 = array(new Class1(), new Class1(), newClass()); //Array of 3 Class1 instances
```